# ReacJs не работает сетка bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, reactjs, center

Через npm подключил bootstrap к проекту. В index.js подключил css файлы

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css"
```

Стили все работают, а классы для разметки типа "align-self-start", "align-items-center" и т.д. нет. Копирую пример с официальной документации bootstrap

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Одна из трёх колонок
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня отображается просто 3 подряд одинаковых столбца
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Версия Bootstrap какая?

Comment: @mix "bootstrap": "^4.2.1"

Comment: попробуйте через cdn в `index.html` подключить и посмотреть работают классы или нет https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @mix  неа, все равно не работает

Comment: а, стоп, я не заметил стили. вы же блоку не дали `display: flex`. сейчас оформлю ответ

Comment: Не поверите, все равно не работает. Но если говорить о display: flex, то класс row так же задает display: flex, следует класс d-flex не обязателен, тем не менее , у меня ничего не работает. Я уже даже отдельный html файл создал , тоже не работает

Comment: да, в новой версии у `row` тоже `display: flex` стоит, вы правы. тем не менее, проблема у вас не в бутстрап и не в реакт тоже.

Comment: @mix Все равно Большое спасибо!